# Missing Drupal Blocks after update via Composer

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

We recently got all our Drupal Modules into Composer as they were originally installed not using Composer.

Drupal 8.3.6 (updated via Composer from version 8.2.7)

After we got everything into Composer, we could update Drupal itself and all its Modules. Now, some blocks are no longer showing on certain pages.

After opening and saving (without edit) each block, most of them would show.

One example is a Frontpage hero block at the top of the home page. It does not use a 3rd party module, but rather built using Drupal itself. Block Category: "Lists (Views)"
Under Configure Block, "Pages" is set to , which does not cause it to show on the home page. If I remove  and keep it blank, it will show on some pages, but not others which includes the frontpage.

The site is currently in a dev environment that is not accessible without VPN access, so I cannot provide a link.

Thank you in advance for any direction or advice.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to try using Registry Rebuild to update the installation location info. https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild.

Clearing cache is always suggested, but I assume you've done that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for the delay. It seems that "./drush registry rebuild" is not available in D8. Looking at "vendor/drupal/console-core/config/drush.yml", it appears that "./drush cache-rebuild;" does the same thing. I tried this and it did not solve my issue. Any other ideas are most certainly welcome. Thank you!